# EGMO Problem 3.20 (BAMO 2013/3)

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-transformation

The problem statement follows:

> Let $H$ be the orthocenter of an acute angle triangle $ABC$. Consider the circumcenters of triangles $ABH$, $ BCH$, and $CAH$. Prove that they are the vertices of a triangle that is congruent to $ABC$.

So I first showed that the orthocenter of $ABC$ is the circumcenter of the second triangle, $A'B'C'$ and the circumcenter of $ABC$ is the orthocenter of $A'B'C'$. Next if we take a homothety $h$ at $N_9$ of $ABC$ with scale factor $-1$, this will send $H$ to $O$ and vice versa and we'll get a congruent triangle.

But my question is, how do I prove that the triangle formed by taking the homothety is the very triangle in the question, namely $A'B'C'$?

Comment: You want to prove that $A'$ is the reflection of $A$ through $N_9$ (the center of the nine-point circle of $\triangle ABC$). This is equivalent to saying that the homothety with center $A$ and factor $1/2$ sends $A'$ to $N_9$. Well... This homothety sends $B$, $C$ and $H$ to three points that are known to lie on the nine-point circle, and thus sends the circumcircle of $\triangle BCH$ to the nine-point circle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you know the fact that circle $BCH$ is a reflection of circle $ABC$ acros $BC$. Similary is true for the other two circles.

So $$AC' = AO = CO = CA'$$

and by easy angle chase you can see $AC'||CA'$ so $A'CAC'$ is paralelogram, so $A'C' = AC$ and we are done.

[image]

Comment: Hey! I know I am very late but i really need help. Actually i am new to olympiad geometry and i just wish to know how do we get to the conclusion that $AC'||CA'$?

Answer (score 0):

$B'C'\;\bot\;AH$ and $BC\;\bot\;AH$, so $BC\;||\; B'C'$.

Similarly, $AB\;||\;A'B'$ and $AC\;||\;A'C'$.

This implies $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C'$

---

$A'H={BC\over2\sin\angle BHC}={a\over2\sin A}=R$.

Similarly, $B'H=C'H=R$.

So $H$ is the circumcentre of $\triangle A'B'C'$, and its circumradius is $R$, the same as the circumradius of $\triangle ABC$.

Since $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C'$, equal circumradii allow us to get $\triangle ABC \cong \triangle A'B'C'$.