# If $H$ is the orthocenter of acute triangle $ABC$, then the circumcenters of triangles $ABH$, $BCH$, $CAH$ determine a triangle congruent to $ABC$

Tags: geometry

EGMO (BAMO 2013/3)

> Let $H$ be the orthocenter of an acute triangle $\triangle ABC$.
>   Consider the circumcenters of triangles $\triangle ABH$, $\triangle BCH$, and $\triangle CAH$. Prove that they are the vertices of a triangle that is congruent to $\triangle ABC$.

I solved the problem by showing that the circumcenters are found by taking the homothety of the original vertices to the nine-point circle with a scale factor of $-1$, thus they are congruent.

In the book, the hint said "Show that $$O_BO_C = 2(1/2)BC$$" where $O_b, O_c$ are the circumcenters. I am wondering how someone would get this using homothety.

Comment: Also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104959/egmo-problem-3-20-bamo-2013-3?rq=1)